# Web hosting providers support full FTP access, but is it secure?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ftp, web-hosting

All web hosting providers support full FTP access but many do not support SFTP.
But how do they ensure FTP is secure? FTP sends information (passwords, etc) in clear-text right.

I was told by one of the Sales/Support staff from one of the hosting providers that since users get individual access to FTP accounts via CPanel then the access to the user's website directory using FTP is secure.

Is this true?

**SSL question:**

Also I would like to use SSL on the admin login with my hosted customized wordpress website. What is involved in this? I know it is possible to configure this http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL
But the web hosting provided need to support SSL? Is there a need for certificate, etc and by who?

Comment: FTP stands for File Transfer Protocol.So basically it allows for transfering files between server and developer machine.I don't think it's unsecure.Because FTP user can't make any issues on the sever or getting control of the sever.Biggest harm that can be done is deleting all the files on the server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: There are many other questions on stackoverflow unrelated to programming: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ftp especially on FTP. Would you down vote those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can passively sniff the traffic you see username and password used by the FTP user in clear, unless the client uses FTPS. This is about the security you get with plain telnet (instead of SSH) or authorized access to mail servers which are not protected by TLS (most providers now offer TLS).

Once you have the credentials you can compromise the account. This is not only deleting the data (i.e. denial of service), but grab any sensitive data, manipulate data to spread false information etc. If the credentials are also usable for SSH an attacker can log into the system as an unprivileged user and from there it is often not far away to a whole system compromise. Also, the same credentials are often used to access the users email so you can compromise this too.

Which means, yes, it is completely insecure.

Apart from that, don't mix up FTPS and SFTP. FTPS is the FTP protocol with TLS extended, while SFTP is file transfer over SSH. Some clients like FileZilla support both and if you have the choice prefer SFTP because it is much less hassle with firewalls.